# Jmeter Report Making Approach

Tags: jmeter, report

Usually I do run the Jmeter tests multiple times and do select a consistent result out of all runs. And further use the statistics to make the Jmeter Report.

But someone asks from my team that, we need to calculate the Average of all runs and use it for Report making.

If I do so, then I can not generate the in-built Graphs which Jmeter provides. And also the statistics which I present for the test is also not the original it's manipulated/altered by calculating the Average.

Which is the good approach to follow?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Merge Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) in order to join 2 or more results files into a single one and apply your analysis solution(s) onto this generated aggregate result. Moreover you will be able to compare different test runs results.

[image: JMeter merge results]

You can install the tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Merge Results tool]

Answer (score 0):

I am developing now one tool based on Python + Django + Postgres which will help to run/parse/analyze/monitor JMeter load tests and compare results. In`s on some early stage but already not so bad( but sadly bad documented)
https://github.com/v0devil/JMeter-Control-Center

Also there is static report generator based on Python + Pandas. Maybe you can modify it for your tasks :) https://github.com/v0devil/jmeter_jenkins_report_generator